# Caching SHOUTcast API results

Tags: android, caching, shoutcast

I have just become a SHOUTcast partner and received my DevID.

I read pretty much everything here: 
[SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API](http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_Radio_Directory_API)

and here: [SHOUTcast_API_License_Agreement](http://wiki.shoutcast.com/wiki/SHOUTcast_API_License_Agreement)

And I have a tough question: should I cache the results from their API calls?

If decided to cache, I would be going against what is requested in the SHOUTcast Radio Directory API:

> Do not cache the XML for more than 1 day, as station ID's can and will change.

If I did not cache anything, I would be going against the SHOUTcast API License Agreement:

> Please do not hammer the servers. We request reasonable usage and recommend that you utilize local caching.

Moreover, let's suppose I decide to cache results. Since those results are 100% based on users' queries, **wouldn't it be somewhat silly to cache those results, as my app's users would probably enter different queries every time**????

In an effort to try to solve my problem, I had the idea of downloading the entire SHOUTcast database, once a day/week, and then, upload it to my own server. Afterwards, my app would send all queries to my server, and wouldn't bother SHOUTcast's servers at all.

The problem with such an approach, though, is that I could not find a way to download the entire SHOUTcast database at once, like we can do with IceCast's [dir.xiph.org/yp.xml](http://dir.xiph.org/yp.xml).

What should I do next???? How should I proceed?

I'm afraid of hurting the SHOUTcast API License Agreement and getting my DevId revoked:

> We reserve the right to revoke access for DevIDs which abuse the system.

Has anyone here ever created an application that connects to SHOUTcast's directory? If so, which approach have you used not to be banned?

Comment: I'd say it's just a matter of using common sense. Any request that is likely to return different data each time (i.e any form of searching) doesn't make much sense to have its results cached. Vice versa: data that is unlikely to change with every request (more or 'static' data) could/should be cached. That's probably worth the effort, even it's valid for just 24 hours, as it can make your app feel a lot more responsive (and potentially work in a (semi) offline mode).

Comment: Hey carlo, I made a question here which is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49395722/shoutcast-api-is-completely-useless-due-to-changing-ids. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness, I will answer my own question with the solution I came up with.

After a lot of research I decided to create a 30-minute cache, from which I retrieve the last results. Should the user change the search filter, or should the cache expire, all cached results are cleared, a new request is made to SHOUTcast's servers and a new cache is created.

The code can be found here:

[ShoutcastRadioStationList.java](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/src/br/com/carlosrafaelgn/fplay/list/ShoutcastRadioStationList.java)

[RadioStationCache.java](https://github.com/carlosrafaelgn/FPlayAndroid/blob/master/src/br/com/carlosrafaelgn/fplay/list/RadioStationCache.java)